# Using Index + filter in Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I would appreciate some help with this spreadsheet issue. I am trying to automate column B to find the next shipment in the restock row and column C to find that same shipment from the same restock row and by using offset to go to the date cell once that next shipment (950) is found. (The table on the right.)

My problem that the formula that I used with the filter function in C2 is giving me an error. However, if in that same formula, I remove the filter (**which is set based on date conditions and should start based on today's date in any given date**) and I set the range manually, it works fine (see cell C5)

Here it is the link to my sample ([here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-3ZZBar2BExaFhOMzpjpAbDFMTDmupuX4x0irwv3ixM/edit?usp=sharing))

Thanks for any help in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see why you should use `index(match())` when `filter()` seems capable of getting those values directly. Try these formulas:

```
=iferror( +filter( 
  F$3:$3, 
  not(isblank(F$3:$3)), 
  F$1:$1 >= A10 
) )
```

```
=iferror( +filter( 
  F$1:$1, 
  not(isblank(F$3:$3)), 
  F$1:$1 >= A10 
) )
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-3ZZBar2BExaFhOMzpjpAbDFMTDmupuX4x0irwv3ixM/edit#gid=0).

Comment: HI! thank you so much for taking a look at my issue. However, what I need to do is dynamic. I just need the next value based on today's date. So I just need one column showing the next restock and the next column showing the date. Based on today() to the end of the year.

Comment: I think that the formulas above do exactly that provided that you put `=today()` in cell `A10`. If you need more help, please show your _hand-entered_ expected results in the sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Let check, I think you got it!

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! that is exactly what I needed!

Comment: By the way, what is the function of that + symbol before FILTER?

Comment: The `filter()` function will return multiple results when there are multiple matches. The `+` gets just the first one.

Comment: Thank you so much again!